# SQL XML Bulk Load Error when I try to create and populate database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xsd, sql-server-2012

I´m working with XML data which have lot of XSD files. To load this data to database (I need to create tables from XSDs) I cannot use, xsd2DB (because the XSDs contain union and list), neither SSID project. So I tried Bulk load but there is an error: **Schema: multiple base for a derived type on nilReason is not supported (HResult>0x80004005)**.

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

below this is my C# code and URL to XSD http://www.cuzk.cz/GenerujSoubor.ashx?NAZEV=10-AXSD (which are distributed by CZECH OFFICE FOR SURVEYING, MAPPING AND CADASTRE); the main XSD file in the zip is in path: *...\ruian\xsd\vymenny_format*

```
   SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class objBL = new SQLXMLBulkLoad4Class();
         objBL.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;server=mypc\\SQLSer; database=test;integrated security=SSPI";


   objBL.BulkLoad = true;
   objBL.SchemaGen = true;
   objBL.SGUseID = true;
   objBL.CheckConstraints = true;
   objBL.ForceTableLock = true;
   objBL.KeepIdentity = false;
   objBL.ErrorLogFile = filePath + "\\Project_Errors\\error.txt";
   objBL.Execute(@"D:\data\ruian\xsd\vymenny_format\test.xsd", @"D:\data\ruian\xsd\vymenny_format\test_data.xml");
   objBL.Execute(@"D:\data_RUIAN\ruian\xsd\vymenny_format\VymennyFormatTypy.xsd", @"D:\data_RUIAN\data\20130430_OB_500071_UKSH.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all possible XSD can be translated automatically in a database schema - I am afraid you are in one of this cases.

You'd have to create the database table manually and map the XML to them.